# how to make a C# struct to be compatible with both x86 and x64 without using macro?

Tags: c#, .net, c, struct

considering the following code, is there any way to get rid of #if #else #endif macro? make the struct compatible with x86 and x64 system!

```
    public struct SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DATA
{
    #if bit32
    public int cbSize;
    #else
    public Int64 cbSize;
    #endif
    public GUID InterfaceClassGuid;
    public int Flags;
    public int Reserved;
}
```

I tried to make two struct but it fails because the complexity of the current code is overwhelming.

this struct is used by some api that import from dll by using DllImporting

Comment: What is your SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DATA? Does it need the struct to have different sized integers for the two platforms? If not, just use the regular 32 bit int and call it good.

Comment: Are you using it to make a "raw" cast from/to byte buffer? If yes, make two structs and decide in runtime, because it depends on input data.

Comment: any other way to do this without making two struts?

Comment: It really depends on what you need it for. If you are in control of all the code that uses the struct, simply decide on what types to use for both architectures. It's different if a third-party library expects different types based on architecture.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `IntPtr` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would normally use IntPtr instead, 4 bytes in 32-bit mode, 8 bytes in 64-bit mode.

But that would be incorrect, you can tell from the [winapi declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that the field is declared as DWORD.  It is 4 bytes in 64-bit mode as well.

Comment: thanks man, I use IntPtr and it works. except the part that every time  I had to cast it to a IntPtr when I assign a value to cbSize

Comment: It is like talking a wall and having to listen to it complaining being made out of bricks.